# Polymorphic Association in rails

Tags: polymorphism, associations

Is it possible to change the type of polymorphic association in Rails?
Like we don't want to add any type but we do want to add the table columns in that type ?
That is if I have a table of users(having different records of seller and buyer) and a Join table as polymorphic.
I don't want to add the type as User but I do want to add type as 'Buyer' or 'Seller' in that Join table.
Any Suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you mixing polymorphic associations with single table inheritance (User model has two sub-models: Seller and Buyer).

I have a hard time understanding your questions but I think what you need is just validations on the `_type` column in your join model.